# How to map an int to a boolean

Tags: automapper

I'm using AutoMapper 5.2. I currently have a mapping statement that looks as follows:

```
 CreateMap<JeffreysOnline.Data.Customer, JeffreysOnline.Entities.Customer>()
                .ForMember(s => s.CustomerWant, t => t.Ignore());
```

Both the Customer table and Customer entity have a field named BadChecks. In the database it's an int. I recently changed the type to a bool in my entity. AutoMapper is now giving me the following error:

```
Unable to create a map expression from Customer.BadChecks (System.Int16) to Customer.BadChecks (System.Boolean) Mapping types: Customer -> Customer JeffreysOnline.Data.Customer -> JeffreysOnline.Entities.Customer Type Map configuration: Customer -> Customer JeffreysOnline.Data.Customer -> JeffreysOnline.Entities.Customer Property: BadChecks
```

It seems AutoMapper doesn't know how to map from an int to a boolean. Is it possible for me to help AutoMapper with this?

It may be helpful to know that in my DAL, I'm using ProjectTo() to pass an IQueryable to another method that is attempting to access the data, and therefore the mapping is occurring (an error being generated). My DAL code looks like this:

```
return entityList.OrderBy(row => row.LastName).ProjectTo<Entities.Customer>();
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Automapper 6.0.2 - works without any ForMember... null, 0 = false, values >= 1 are mapped to true.

In Automapper 6.0.2 - other way:

```
    class nnnProfile : Profile
    {
        CreateMap<src, dst>()
            .ForMember(d => d.Decision, opt => opt.ResolveUsing<CustomBoolResolver>());    
    }
```

Resolver:

```
public class CustomBoolResolver : IValueResolver<src, dst, bool>
{
    public bool Resolve(src source, dst destination, bool destMember,
        ResolutionContext context)
    {
        return source.Decision == 1;
    }
}
```

but this is per Destination, so not much flexible.

According to this page:
http://taswar.zeytinsoft.com/automapper-mapping-objects-part-5-of-7-customresolver/

In past you could write a custom resolver with just Source and target type.

Comment: So Automapper 6.0.2 has a default mapping setup for int to bool?

Answer (score 2):

I don't think *I* would know how to map from int to a boolean.

If you do figure out how that should happen, you'll need to create a mapping from int to boolean.:

```
CreateMap<int, bool>().ProjectUsing(src => src != 0);
```

Completely guessing there. But since you're using ProjectTo, you'll need to use ProjectUsing so that the expression makes it allllll the way down to your DAL.

Remember, when using ProjectUsing, AutoMapper isn't actually executing the mapping. It's creating a LINQ "Select" expression that it passes down to your query provider (EF maybe?). So you'll need to make sure that whatever you use in your projection expression, EF can support translating that eventually into SQL.